# How to recover permanently deleted blog posts?

Tags: customization, trash

I accidentally deleted about 20 blog posts and they were in my trash folder for over a month and now have permanently deleted. I was wondering if there's a way to recover these? For example I have seen mention of MySql database and phpMyAdmin, and was wondering if these would be applicable in my case and, if so, how do I use them?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Hottie Rizwan, Do you found any solution? If yes, please share. Thanks in advance

Comment: @TayyabChaudhary you should not have posted the comment as a solution to the question, you got flagged by the anti-spam system, and could be banned automatically if you do it again. As for the answer, see Max's answer

Comment: Same problem here. Unfortunately, I noticed it too late by accident. Today I discovered that one of my most-read posts at huglero.com was absent. I was like, how come that's happening?? Then I realized that I lost more than 15 popular posts. I went to achieve org and found some of them. But I want to ask how is that possible? Someone hacked my site and deleted all those posts? Or is there a chance that I deleted them with database optimizer plugins? Is it possible?

Comment: I also deleted 31 posts just because I was editing my website design, I don't know what to do please help me

Comment: @amine I converted your "answer" into a comment, don't post replies as solutions again. In the meantime see  the answers posted, if you did not make some form of backup/copy then that data is lost forever with zero recovery options, there is nothing you can do to get them back, _they're gone_.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have backups of your database? If not, ask your hosting provider if they have backup copies of your database from the time before the posts were deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to recover deleted posts from within WordPress or current MySQL database. That's because it's called *Permanently* delete.

The only opportunity to recover deleted posts is to roll back the whole database from the backup if it exists. Check your hosting panel — may be you have Automatic Backups setting enabled.